# Assigning values to dynamic floating point array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, scanf

I used `malloc()` to make an array of floating point numbers like so:

```
float*x1;

x1 = (float*)malloc((vertexes/3)*sizeof(float)); 

if(x1 == NULL)
{
    printf("Out Of Memory");
    getchar(); return(1);
}
```

So far, it seems like the above is fine based on my limited knowledge, however when I attempt to use that array like this:
    `fscanf(stl,"%f",x1[N]);` it does not work.
The N in brackets after the x1 is a variable that normally gets incremented, but for testing purposes I quoted out all that and just used any number that was within the range of the array like 3 for example. When I try to do this, the program compiles and runs fine until it hits the `fscanf` line of code. at that point it crashes and windows says its trying to find a solution to the problem. I tried using my dynamic array by putting `x1[3] = 12345` which seemed to work, because `printf("%f",x1[3]);` outputted `12345` like it was supposed to. This leads me to believe the problem lies within `fscanf(stl,"%f",x1[N]);` but I have no clue why.

Thanks in advance for any advice, it is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: No errors or warnings are printed?

Comment: Plural of "vertex" is "vertices" :). Looks like @paxdiablo isolated the cause of your failure.

Comment: @mbratch, that's _one_ of the plural forms though it may depend on which English variant you're referring to :-) Here in the great southern land at least, both are allowed.

Comment: @paxiablo I see. Well, I guess I've blown my cover. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `scanf` family, you need to provide the *address* of the variable you want populated, such as:

```
fscanf (stl, "%f", &(x1[N]));
```

From the `C11` standard `7.20.6.2 The fscanf function / 12` (my emphasis):

> `a,e,f,g:` Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or NaN, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtod function. The corresponding argument shall be a **pointer** to floating.

---

And, just a couple of other points:

- it's not a good idea to explicitly cast the return value from `malloc` in C. It can hide certain subtle errors, and C will happily implicitly cast without it.
- it's usually a good idea to check the return value from the `scanf` family since it gives you the number of items successfully scanned. If that's not what you asked for, you should take appropriate action.

Comment: Thank-You paxdiablo, it works exactly as it should now. I was just wondering though, did the way I have it try to set a value to the pointer instead of the array? And as for the `malloc` thing I don't understand what you mean. I just googled how to make dynamic arrays and then I copied it and changed the parameters.

Comment: @user1888665: on the `malloc` (second) question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc. Re the first question, it would have taken the current (arbitrary) _value_ of `x1[N]` and used that as a pointer to populate an (arbitrary) memory block. Not a good idea :-)